# How to put image into the margin corner?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, margins, geometry

Given `geometry` margins like

```
\geometry{left=20mm, right=20mm, top=20mm, bottom=20mm}
```

what's the right way to put (as a top overlay) an image right into the margins' top right corner (but not onto the page's corner - that's too far)?

I'm currently trying

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
   \node[anchor=north east,inner sep=0pt] at (current page.north east)
              {\includegraphics{IMAGE.jpg}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

but that puts into the page corner. Is `tikz` right for this?

Comment: I think TikZ is not right for you so far, because you have not realised the cleaner TikZ code for your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tikzpagenodes` package provides nodes like `current page text area` for this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[left=20mm, right=20mm, top=20mm, bottom=20mm,showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
   \node[anchor=north east,inner sep=0pt] at (current page text area.north east)
              {\includegraphics{example-image}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put image via `node` of TikZ. The option `anchor` can be completely ignored: `\node[anchor=north east]{...}` is the same as `\node[below right]{...}`.

[image]

```
% image from https://lichngaytot.com/phong-thuy/hoa-tra-loai-hoa-phong-thuy-xinh-dep-vuong-tai-284-185665.html
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\path (current page.north west) 
node[scale=.5,below right]    
{\includegraphics{hoatra}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\path (current page.center) 
node[xscale=.6,yscale=.4,rotate=25]    
{\includegraphics{hoatra}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```