# How to align an image to the top of page/paper using tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I have an image which spans the `paperwidth`.  I have added the image by setting its `width = \paperwidth` and anchoring it at `(current page.north)` or at `(current page.center)` using `tikz`. Now to align the top edge of the image I had to manually add a `yshift` with trial and error to make it work. Is there any way in which the image can be made to align to the top of the page automatically? I have several images of varying heights and hence doing this manually would mean to adjust `yshift` for each image separately. I tried to use `shift={(current page.north)` along the line suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/320123/a-logo-on-top-of-a-colored-titlepage/320148#320148), but somehow it leaves a small gap between the top and the image.  How do I achieve this without a manual adjustment?

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay] 
 \node  [yshift=-9.45cm] at (current page.north) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{Rose.jpg}};
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Source for the image: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ac/Rose_hip_02_ies.jpg

Comment: See also: [tikz pgf - How to put image into the margin corner? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/517402/how-to-put-image-into-the-margin-corner)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the options `anchor=north, inner sep=0pt` seems to place it at the correct spot:

[image]

I have included the `showframe` package so that it is clear where the normal text would go.

##### Note:

- The small gray border is an artifact of the image capture process.

#### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay] 
 \node  [anchor=north, inner sep=0pt] at (current page.north) 
     {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{../images/Rose.jpg}};
\end{tikzpicture}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: [below] also works.  Still need [inner sep=0pt] of course.  Now, trying to avoid writing over the top is a bit tricky.